# Can a link have both an onclick jquery and javascript event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, toggle, execute

I have a link that jQuery listens to, and if clicked it will toggle another div. The link also has an onclick javascript action. When I click the link, the div I want to toggle shows, but the javascript doesn't execute.

1. Is it possible to get the javascript to execute AND have jQuery toggle the div?
2. If so what would I put in the jQuery code to allow the link to execute the onclick javascript action?

jQuery script

```
$(function() {
  $('#links a').live('click', function() {
  $("#showall").toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

my link

```
<div id ="links">
  <a href="some javascript" onclick="javascript">Play</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for me the following is working in Chrome, Firefox and IE. Both pure Javascript (onclick) and jQuery click() get executed.

```
<html>                                                                  
 <head>                                                                  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>          
 <script type="text/javascript">                                         
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            $('div').toggle();
        });
   });                                    
 </script>                                                               
 </head>                                                                 
 <body>                                                                  
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('original onclick')">Click me</a>
    <div>
        Some div content...
    </div>
 </body>                                                                 
 </html>
```

Comment: And [verified with a JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wSnJP/). +1 =)

Comment: jQuery just attaches to the event handlers, it doesn't replace them. You can even have multiple jQuery functions binding to the same event.